# (Java SE/Android) cross platform logging

Tags: java, android, logging

I want this library I'm working on to have logging support, but Android and SE have their own ways of logging. In SE you can use `System.out.println` methods or the `java.util.logging.Logger` class. Android uses `android.util.Log` to log on logcat. At first I used reflection to check if android was usable, then reflectively call the log methods in `Log.class`; but that wasn't a good idea.

My solution is to have the developers using my library handle logs themselves. There will be a Handler interface they set and has an onLog method

```
public void onLog(int level, String tag, String msg);
```

The library will call the onLog method on the handlers in my custom Logger class. Is it a good idea to have developers handle the logs instead of the library itself? Seems to be the best solution so far and if I document it good then it should't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that logging should be delegated to clients, and your homegrown approach is indeed sensible.

IMO, the [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) facade would be ideal for your situation. Your library would include the `slf4j-api` jar and contain SLF4J logging statements. If clients wanted logging, they'd just drop in a logging backend (and an optional config file) into their application's classpath to capture/view your log statements.

The advantages to this approach are that it grants clients the most control with zero coding required to get logging; and that it allows the client to choose among many available backends.

I would use [`logback`](http://logback.qos.ch) as the backend for J2SE apps and [`logback-android`](http://logback.qos.ch/android/) for Android.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the `slf4j` logging library. I wish I could edit my other comment I made before about not using them. First time using a one so I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

You can try microlog

http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/

It can help you use a consistent logging mechanism across android and java. If you use slf4j, it can be used as a wrapper both for microlog (in case of your android project) and log4j (for your java projects)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't think I'm going to use separate logging libraries since I'm not logging a lot of data. I think I will go with my solution since I tested it out and works well. Plus it will allow users to handle the logs for logging libraries like you mentioned.